# Did the cove molding that I'm removing support the drywall panels behind it?

Tags: drywall

just looking for a little reassurance really - decorating the hallway in a house we have recently moved in to, The plaster coving has been done very poorly - very uneven, very visible joins etc. I was in 2 minds whether to remove and replace but knew if I didn't it would annoy me. The coving is plaster, I will replace with the polystyrene coving. As i started removing the coving there is quite a large gap between the sheet plaster on the wall and the sheet plaster on the ceiling - like an inch or so. I kind of expected the two to meet. There's no danger that the coving was helping support the roof sheets and by removing the coving I risk the roof sheets dropping?

Comment: Plaster or drywall (gypsum panels)? There's a significant difference.

Comment: Gypsum panels not lath and plaster

Answer (score 1):

No, the decorative cove molding is not supporting your drywall sheets. They'll be securely fastened with nails or screws.

Comment: Cheers - Logic told me that would be the case but then my wife started putting doubts in my head !

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done before. Obviously the trim/coving can't hold drywall together, but if you're planning to put trim/coving up there's no reason to join the drywall or tape the corners. I don't recommend doing it that way, tho.

The nails/screws are hidden with mud before painting.

Comment: Probably worth adding - the whole point of trim/coving is to hide the gaps between wall and ceiling. In the OP's house it looks like that was taken to extremes though, and not even bothering to make the gap small.

Answer (score 0):

NO...  simple huh? Trim does not support drywall.